# discord bot: client.start(Token) not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

trying to run a discord bot

this is the code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN: str = "Token"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected')

client.start(TOKEN)
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:/Users/josep/Desktop/unsettler/unsettler.py
C:/Users/josep/Desktop/unsettler/unsettler.py:12: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.start' was never awaited
  client.start(TOKEN)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I tried using client.run instead of client.start, but it triggers more errors. How do I fix this?

edit: the errors I got from client run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 245, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/josep/Desktop/unsettler/unsettler.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 295, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000216FCD9FDC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 711, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\josep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 504, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Can you show what error messages you are getting from `client.run`? `client.run` and `client.start` are not equivalent functions, as `client.start` needs to be manually initialized into the event loop, whereas `client.run` abstracts that process and makes it simpler to use.

Answer (score 3):

According to the traceback for `client.run`, the `RuntimeError` at the bottom was derived from this exception:

```
LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.')
```

Essentially, check that you copied the correct token into the `TOKEN` variable. When you go to the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) and click on your application, make sure that you copy the *bot token* (you will find it in the Bot tab on the left) and not the client secret or client ID.

Comment: Thank you so much! It turned out I was using the client secret and not the token.